# Dynamic object creation from user input

Tags: java, object, dynamic, user-input

I have a two classes, `Student` containing some basic info, and `Course`, containing some basic info and an `ArrayList` of `Student` objects. I want to dynamically (from user input) populate new instances of both classes. For example, user is prompted for course name, teacher and asked if they want to add students to the course. When done with the course and all the students' information, the loop goes back to asking to add another course.
What I do is, create a `Course` object and then add students. I manage `Student` objects by just creating them after collecting user unput with `courseInstance.addStudent(new Student(name, age, phone))`. It all works well for one course, but how do I manage multiple Course object, dynamically created from input?
Here is a code example:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Course course = new Course();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String ans;
    String name;
    String gender;
    String phone;
    int age;

    System.out.print("Enter course name: ");
    ans = in.nextLine();
    course.setName(ans);

    System.out.print("Enter teacher name: ");
    ans = in.nextLine();
    course.setTeacher(ans);

    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Add student (yes or exit): ");
        ans = in.nextLine();

        if (ans.equals("exit")) {
            break;
        }

        System.out.print("Enter name: ");
        name = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter age: ");
        age = in.nextInt();
        in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter gender: ");
        gender = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter phone number: ");
        phone = in.nextLine();

        course.addStudent(new Student(age, name, phone, gender));
    }

    in.close();
    System.out.print(course);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about having a List of `Course` objects, and asking (in your `while(true)` loop) what course each student is registering to?

Answer (score 0):

Create a List which you can populate with courses like this:

```
ArrayList<Course> courses = new ArrayList<Course>();
```

When a student enters a name from the course, check if the course exists in the array. If not, add it to the array, else get it from the array and add the student.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Name seems to be the primary attribute to identify a course, you should override the equals(Object o) method of course so it compares the two names of the courses.

```
public boolean equals(Object o){
    return this.getName().equals((Course)o.getName());
}
```

Then you can simply have a List to store your courses and ask the list if it contains a specific course or not. If not you can add it to the list, otherwise you can add students or teachers to the already existing course.
EDIT: It should be getName() on both courses